# Permanently show hidden directories

Tags: terminal, folders, macos

I am trying to repair a friend's USB drive that got a virus. All directories became .lnk and the original ones were hidden. I don't know how to permanently show the folders.
I've used `sudo chflags nohidden /path` but it doesn't work permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Files & folders that start with a period will always be hidden in the Finder, and in Terminal listings (ls command, unless you use the -a flag i.e. "ls -a"), If renaming the folders is acceptable, then just remove the period from the folders you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

#### In Terminal

To show all hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder
```

To hide hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder
```

#### With an application

You can download one of many applications that do this on mouse click. There are many, but the first one that comes up in a google search is [Show Hide Invisible Files](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22318/show-hide-invisible-files).

Answer (score 0):

`chflags nohidden` should be permanent, but it doesn't affect files that start with a period.

This makes Finder show all hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true; killall Finder
```